# how to resolve Error in Loop to get GPO from OU

Tags: powershell

I created a PS script to find GPOs linked in an OU and subOUs, what am I doing wrong? I get this error and am confused about the message:

> Get-ADOrganizationalUnit : Cannot bind parameter 'Identity'. Cannot
>   convert the "@{DistinguishedName=OU=Windows 7,DC=domain,DC=com}" value
>   of type
>   "Selected.Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADOrganizationalUnit"
>   to type "Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADOrganization alUnit".
>   At F:\Untitled4.ps1:11 char:39
>   + $LinkedGPOs = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit <<<<  $OU | select-object -ExpandProperty LinkedGroupPolicyObjects
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ADOrganizationalUnit], ParameterBindingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADOrganizationalUnit

```
get-module activedirectory,grouppolicy

$exportFilePath = "c:\temp\AllGPOsWin7-report date $(get-date -f dd-MM-yyyy).csv"
$OU = "ou=Windows 7,dc=domain,dc=com"

$AllSubOU = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -SearchBase $OU -SearchScope Subtree -Filter * | 
     Select-Object DistinguishedName

foreach ($OU in $AllSubOU){
$OU
$LinkedGPOs = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit $OU | select-object -ExpandProperty LinkedGroupPolicyObjects

$LinkedGPOGUID = $LinkedGPOs | foreach-object{$_.substring(4,36)}

$GPOName = $LinkedGPOGUID | foreach-object{get-gpo -guid $_ | select-object displayname}

$OU,$ListGPO -join "," | Out-File -FilePath $exportFilePath -Append -Width 200
```

Comment: Don't know... What have you tried and what errors are you getting? Some code would be wonderful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with your

```
$AllSubOU = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -SearchBase $OU -SearchScope Subtree -Filter * | 
 Select-Object DistinguishedName
```

command, this should be change to

```
$AllSubOU = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -SearchBase $OU -SearchScope Subtree -Filter * | 
 Select-Object -ExpandProperty DistinguishedName
```

Since you didn't specify the expand part, PowerShell was returning it inside a container. Hence the OU being in curly brackets {} in the error code

**UPDATE** - Following from the comments on this answer, please see below:

```
#create a new hashtable
$hashTable = [hashtable]::new{}

#define the root OU
$rootOU = "OU=computers,DC=domain,DC=local"

#get all the sub OU in the root OU
$allSubOU = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -SearchBase $rootOU -SearchScope Subtree -Filter * | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DistinguishedName

#loop through the sub OUs
foreach ($subOU in $allSubOU){

    #get the linked GPO objects on the OU
    $linkedGPO = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit $subOU | Select-Object -ExpandProperty LinkedGroupPolicyObjects

    #if the OU has a GPO then run through them
    if ($linkedGPO){

        #adding name to hashtable for current OU
        $hashTable.Add($subOU, @())

        #running through each GPO in sub OU
        foreach($GPO in $linkedGPO){

            #getting GUID from GPO
            $GPOGuid = $GPO.SubString(4,36)

            #using GUID to get displayname of GPO
            $GPOName = Get-GPO -Guid $GPOGuid | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DisplayName

            #add the GPO to the hashttable for the current OU
            $hashTable.$subOU += $GPOName
        }
    }else{
        #ou has no GPOs
        $hashTable.Add($subOU, "No GPO")
    }
}

#enumerate through the hashtable
$hashTable.GetEnumerator() | 
    #add OU to OU column in csv
    Select-Object -Property @{N='OU';E={$_.Name}},
    #add GPO to GPO(s) column in CSV
    @{N='GPO(s)';E={$_.Value}   } | 
    #export to CSV
    Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path PATH
```

Comment: Thanks IT Delinquent :-) I now can get all the sub-OUs listed in my csv output but no GPO name appearing in the list /-:

Comment: @Voilier I think that is an issue in your output. You are exporting a $ListGPO which isn't in the script. I think you have confused this with $LinkedGPOGUID

Comment: Ah yes, thanks, I've corrected that but still get only OU and sub OU with the GPO names under it, can you help? :-)

Comment: @Voilier I have updated the answer, please be kind :D

Comment: Wonderful, many thanks, just replaced the new hash by $hashTable = @{} and working all great. Many thanks for the help and all the other contributors. Have a pleasant day :-)

Answer (score 1):

Note that `$ListGPO` does not exist, and you have to expand the GPOs in case more than one is linked.
Moreover, `Get-ADOrganizationalUnit` has to extract the property `LinkedGroupPolicyObjects` to use it (use `-Properties LinkedGroupPolicyObjects`)
I changed separator in -join from "," to "|" because Distinguishednames have commas inside. 
Also, `-width 200` would cut off GPO when that limit is reached. Would be better to build a custom object and use `Export-Csv` probably.

Find below a tentative script .

```
get-module activedirectory,grouppolicy
$exportFilePath = "c:\temp\AllGPOsWin7-report date $(get-date -f dd-MM-yyyy).csv"
$myOU = "ou=Windows 7,dc=domain,dc=com"

$AllSubOU = (Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -SearchBase $OU -SearchScope Subtree -Filter *).DistinguishedName

foreach ($myOU in $AllSubOU){
    $myOU
    $LinkedGPOs = ( Get-ADOrganizationalUnit $myOU -properties LinkedGroupPolicyObjects).LinkedGroupPolicyObjects
    $LinkedGPOGUID = $LinkedGPOs | foreach-object{$_.substring(4,36)}
    $GPOName = ( $LinkedGPOGUID | foreach-object { (get-gpo -guid $_) | select-object -expandproperty displayname}) -join "|"
    $out = if ( $GPOname ) { $myOU,$GPOName -join "|"} else { $myOU } 
    $out | Out-File -FilePath $exportFilePath -Append -Width 200
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mike, I get an error right after your tentative script with error:     Get-ADOrganizationalUnit : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The argument is null. Supply a non-null argument and try the command again.
At C:\Untitled6.ps1:9 char:45
+     $LinkedGPOs = ( Get-ADOrganizationalUnit <<<<  $myOU -properties LinkedGroupPolicyObjects).LinkedGroupPolicyObject

Comment: My bad. I also changed the First $ou variable to $myou for uniqueness as the original script Is using It in the subsequent foreach. I have corrected It now